# Settings in .yml do not show up in rendered .Rmd

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating an [R Markdown website](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html). However, I am having problems setting the style of the output styling for the document.

I have the `_site.yml` with output arguments that looks like:

```
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    theme: flatly
    highlight: tango
    df_print: paged
    include:
      in_header: "header.html"
      after_body: "footer.html"
    css: "./assets/style.css"
```

And I have a few **.Rmd** files in the same directory that have simple YAML matter:

```
---
title: "A title"
subtitle: "A subtitle"
author: "Name"
---
```

I render the site `rmarkdown::render_site()`. The site and the pages work, but the rendered **.Rmd** files do not show the settings (toc, theme, highlight etc) and css styles defined in the `_site.yml` file. The header and footers also do not show. The path/location of header.html,footer.html and style.css has been verified.

Do I have to specify the output settings in every .Rmd file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to come from the use of `bookdown::html_document2` instead of the rmarkdown function `html_document`.

Using the template provided by RStudio [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-website-examples/tree/master/common-elements), I made some one edit to the settings, adding `theme: flatly`:

```
name: "my-website"
navbar:
  title: "My Website"
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "About"
      href: about.html
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: textmate
    theme: flatly
    include:
      after_body: footer.html
    css: styles.css
```

[image]

Replacing `html_document` with `bookdown::html_document2()`

[image]

Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/render_site.R) of the `render_site` function, there appears no way for it to parse any other output than `html_document`. In fact, when `bookdown::html_document2()` is provided, it will overwrite the `_site.yml` file to:

```
name: my-website
navbar:
  title: My Website
  left:
  - text: Home
    href: index.html
  - text: About
    href: about.html
output:
  html_document:
    lib_dir: site_libs
    self_contained: no
output_dir: _site
```

> If you are looking to benefit from using `html_documents2` within your website, you should check out [blogdown](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown).