# Build R package vignettes with paged data frames

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, devtools, vignette

I'm trying to print pretty tibbles with `df_print: paged` option in my vignettes. My output settings are the following:

```
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    highlight: pygments
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
```

When I build vignettes with `devtools::build_vignettes()` locally I get the right HTML with paged tibbles.

> [image: Screenshot]

But when I build the package on a TeamCity server, the installed package vignettes have tibbles printed in a usual way.

> [image: Screenshot]

I've checked that `rmarkdown::pandoc_available()` is TRUE and `rmarkdown` package version is 2.6 (the `rmarkdown::paged_table` function is from v2.3).

What else do I need to check to build vignettes correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note [Yihui's recommendations for package vignettes](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-package-vignette.html) : keep them lightweight, at least for CRAN.

Comment: I have built 2 packages so far and this book helped me a great deal and serves as checklist for everyone who would like to do so:
https://r-pkgs.org/

Comment: @aschmsu Did my answer help you?

Comment: @eduardokapp I appreciate your effort but it didn't. On the 1: As I've said in the question, I do use `html_document` and I've checked the version. On the 2: maybe it'll work but I really don't want to add a new big import just for this purpose. I want to understand what the problem causes it in my case.

Comment: @aschmsu Ok. But really, you need to provide more details on how your CI/CD process looks like in TeamCity. This is clearly the difference between running locally and not.

Comment: Could you give me a hint what is of interest here? I can just say that the package is built via `devtools::build()` and that's all. Well and also I've checked those things that affect `rmarkdown::paged_table`: the package version and pandoc availability. What should I add? It'll be very useful, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a simple problem. I believe there are two possible solutions:

1: You need to make sure that whatever script is running on your CI/CD in the TeamCity server has the same version of `rmarkdown` you're using locally. A great way to assert this issue is to run the CI/CD script locally (for example, a dockerfile script!) and trying to reproduce the problem. Another probable cause of the problem is that whatever your CI/CD is using to produce the markdown result is overwriting or ignoring certain `yml` tags. Look at [Settings in .yml do not show up in rendered .Rmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774385/settings-in-yml-do-not-show-up-in-rendered-rmd), for example.

2: You can use `DT::datatable` in your vignette, which generates the same type of pretty tibble in a more reliable way.

```
DT::datatable(
your_tibble, 
extensions = c('FixedColumns',"FixedHeader"),
options = list(
     scrollX = TRUE, 
     paging=FALSE,
     fixedHeader=TRUE
)
)
```